# How do I connect to a network without SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking

How do I connect to a network without SSID?

Comment: Need more details? Is the SSID hidden, or do you just not know it? What operating system?

Answer (score 3):

Click the NetworkManager icon in the notification area and choose `Connect to Hidden Wireless Network...`, then fill in the tiny bit of information it asks for.

Comment: Just a note: this wouldn't work if SSID has nonprintable characters, and as I noticed one time, NM does not show networks with these characters in the list, so they are basically 'hidden'.

Answer (score 2):

A network always has a SSID, but may simply not be actively advertising it. Disabling broadcast SSID isn't the same as disabling the SSID. When you disable the broadcast, the SSID isn't included in the information that an outsider would see displayed.

When the SSID is not broadcast, the agent you are using would not be able to pick up the SSID. So, you need to know the SSID which is being set on the access point. Manually giving the SSID to the agent is the easiest way of using the network.

From [Force Vista To Connect To Wireless Network When SSID Is Not Broadcasting](http://www.watchingthenet.com/force-vista-to-connect-to-wireless-network-when-ssid-is-disabled-or-not-not-bradcasting.html):

> There is actually an easy fix to force
>   Vista to connect to Wireless Network
>   that is not broadcasting its SSID.
>
> Just open up the Network and Sharing
>   Center by clicking on Start, type the
>   word network in the Start Menu search
>   box and click on Network and Sharing
>   Center link in the search results. Or
>   go to Start \ Control Panel \ Network
>   and Internet \ Network and Sharing
>   Center.
>
> In the left navigation pane, click on
>   Manage wireless networks.
>
> Then right click on your wireless
>   network connection and select
>   properties.
>
> Click on the check box next to "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting" and click OK to save the
>   change (no reboot is necessary).
>
> Now when you need to connect to
>   wireless network, when SSID is not
>   broadcasting, Vista will make the
>   connection all the time.
>
> Also, as far a security goes, there is
>   no real advantage to hiding the SSID
>   since many programs can see your
>   wireless device when it is not
>   broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some wireless adapters comply with the above and some do not.

In my small sample, the pure-Dell machines (their own wireless adapters & drivers) do.  Apple iPads and iPhones do.  Ralink PCI cards/software using the RA 2561ST chip comply -- they're my favorite because of that and the excellent user interface.  The RT 3560 chip DOES NOT -- if the SSID isn't broadcast, you are sol, no matter if you've been there before, know the ID, and pray your best words.

The little Belkin usb thumb-drive size adapter is also no-go if the SSID is not broadcast.

Not broadcasting an SSID does provide SOME security:  It means passersby, neighbors, etc., won't easily sort your network from others nearby and won't be able to use it, even just to see what happens.  A determined hacker could get in anyhow but not all of us need that level of protection.